# Physical interpretation of a Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, hamiltonian

In natural basis $| 0 \rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\0 \end{pmatrix}$, $| 1 \rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$, what physical situation/model does the following Hamiltonian represent: $H = \alpha \Big( |01 \rangle \langle10| + | 10 \rangle \langle 01| \Big)$?. Here, $| i j \rangle = |i \rangle \otimes |j \rangle$, and $\alpha$ has the dimensions of energy.

Comment: What do the bra-kets $|0 1\rangle$ and so on represent? I feel like the notation is not consistent.

Comment: It is the well known tensor notation. Just edited my question.

Comment: It's an [exchange interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin-exchange_interaction) hamiltonian.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's look at what the Hamiltonian does.

This Hamiltonian has four eigenstates:

- $|00\rangle$, with eigenvalue $0$
- $|11\rangle$, with eigenvalue $0$
- $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|10\rangle+|01\rangle)$, with eigenvalue $\alpha$, and
- $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|10\rangle-|01\rangle)$, with eigenvalue $-\alpha$.

Let's label the last two eigenstates $|T\rangle$ and $|S\rangle$, respectively, for convenience. The energy of each state is $\langle H\rangle = \langle\psi|H|\psi\rangle$; for $|00\rangle$ and $|11\rangle$ the energy is obviously zero, and for $|01\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|T\rangle+|S\rangle)$ and $|01\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|T\rangle-|S\rangle)$, it's also zero. So this Hamiltonian doesn't affect the energy of any of the four "natural" basis states; rather, it affects the energy of particular superpositions of "anti-aligned" states, while totally leaving alone the "aligned" states.

The time evolution of the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian is trivial: for an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian $|a\rangle$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, its time evolution is given by:

$$|\psi(t)\rangle=e^{-i\lambda t/\hbar}|a\rangle$$

So, given these eigenstates and eigenvalues, we can completely describe the time evolution of the Hamiltonian for an arbitrary initial state $|\psi_0\rangle$:

$$|\psi(t)\rangle=\langle00|\psi_0\rangle\cdot|00\rangle+\langle11|\psi_0\rangle\cdot|11\rangle+\langle T|\psi_0\rangle\cdot e^{-i\alpha t/\hbar}|T\rangle+\langle S|\psi_0\rangle\cdot e^{i\alpha t/\hbar}|S\rangle$$

So, if we look at the time evolution of the four "natural" basis states, we get the following:

- For $|\psi_0\rangle=|00\rangle$, we have $|\psi(t)\rangle=|00\rangle$.
- For $|\psi_0\rangle=|11\rangle$, we have $|\psi(t)\rangle=|11\rangle$.
- For $|\psi_0\rangle=|10\rangle$, we have $|\psi(t)\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e^{-i\alpha t/\hbar}|T\rangle+e^{i\alpha t/\hbar}|S\rangle)=\cos(\alpha t/\hbar)|10\rangle-i\sin(\alpha t/\hbar)|01\rangle$.
- For $|\psi_0\rangle=|01\rangle$, we have $|\psi(t)\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e^{-i\alpha t/\hbar}|T\rangle-e^{i\alpha t/\hbar}|S\rangle)=-i\sin(\alpha t/\hbar)|10\rangle+\cos(\alpha t/\hbar)|01\rangle$.

So the $|00\rangle$ and $|11\rangle$ states don't do anything. However, the $|10\rangle$ and $|01\rangle$ states end up *oscillating* between each other as a function of time. In other words, this Hamiltonian *exchanges* the states of the first and second particle, and is therefore called an *exchange interaction*.